# Use a dynamically generated file as configSource in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, configsource

Is there a way to use a generated file as a configSource for a web.config section?

In web.config, I tried a simple:

```
<webParts configSource="webpartsConfig.aspx" />
```

where webpartsConfig.aspx just spits out XML when accessed normally, but not as a configSource. (The literal source code is included as-is, giving an error.)
Any solutions or alternatives?

Motivation for this solution: I have different configuration variables locally and online, and I don't want to juggle multiple config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this doesn't come too late to help, but I would suggest looking at an adaption of the source used in Enterprise Library. Details - http://blogs.msdn.com/tomholl/archive/2006/04/02/entlib2externalconfig.aspx

Then you would be creating a custom ConfigurationSource that reads HttpWebResponses.